# What criterion should I use for this series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

This is probably an easy one, but I'm having trouble solving this series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{(n+1)\sqrt[3]{n+2}}$$

I've tried to use the ratio test, but the result is 1, so the test is inconclusive.  I've also tried Raabe-Duhamel's test, but (if I did it right) my result was $\infty$.

Comment: I suspect a typo, $x^2$ is illogical.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $x=1$*, the general term is asymptotic to $n^{-4/3}$ so that the series converges.

---

*In case the exponent of $x^2$ would be incorrect.